# ng-click not working , no data posted in mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have been trying to learn following through the tutorial "CRUD app with AngularJs, Node js, express js, Bootstrap, EJS, MySQL" by Shiva Adhikari when I realized that I was stuck at part 5 of the tutorial.

My problem

On submitting the form to create a product category, the browser console does nothing.  I'm new, thanks for any help.

**app.js**

```html
// Module Dependencies ============================================================================
var express             = require('express'); // call express
var app                 = express(); // define our app using express
var routes              = require('./routes');
var http                = require('http');
var path                = require('path');
//var methodOverride      = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

var bodyParser          = require('body-parser');
var mysql               = require("mysql");
//var favicon             = require('serve-favicon');
//var morgan              = require('morgan');   // log requests to console



// Environment  =================================================================================


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));


 
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
app.get('/contact', routes.contact);

//app.get('/fileUploader', routes.fileUploader);


var productCategoryRoute = require('./routes/productCategoryRouteConfig.js');
//var productRoute = require('./routes/productRouteConfig.js');


new productCategoryRoute(app);
//new productRoute(app);





http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**createProductCategory.ejs**

```js
<% include index %>  
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">  <%=title %>   </h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="container"
         data-ng-cloak
         data-ng-app="productCategoryModule"
         data-ng-controller="productCategoryController">
         <form
            class="navbar-form navbar-left" role= "search"
            method = "POST"
            name = "formProductCategory"
            >
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="productCategory">  Product Category Name </label>  
                  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                  <input type="text"
                     class="form-control"
                     placeholder="Please Enter Product Category"
                     name="productCategory"
                     id="productCategory"
                     ng-model="productCategory.categoryName"
                     style="width:100%"
                     required>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="productDetails">  Product Category Details </label>  
                  <textarea
                     class="form-control"
                     placeholder="Product Category Details"
                     name="productDetails"
                     id="productDetails"
                     rows="5"
                     cols="30"
                     ng-model="productDetails.categoryDetails"
                     style="width:100%"
                     required></textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group"> <style="padding-left:40%">
                  <button type="button">  <class="btn btn-primary">
                  <ng-click="createProductCategory(productCategory)">Create Product Category</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../javascripts/app/productCategory/productCategoryModule.js"></script>
<script src="../../javascripts/app/productCategory/productCategoryService.js"></script>
<script src="../../javascripts/app/productCategory/productCategoryController.js"></script>
```

**productCategoryRouteConfig**

```js
function productCategoryRouteConfig(app) { 

    this.app = app;
    this.routeTable = [];
    this.init();
} 


// two types of functions add and process, get
productCategoryRouteConfig.prototype.init = function () { 

    var self = this;
    this.addRoutes();
    this.processRoutes();
};


// 1- process routes , depending on get, post, or delete
productCategoryRouteConfig.prototype.processRoutes = function () { 
    var self = this;
    self.routeTable.forEach(function (route) {
        if (route.requestType == 'get') {
            console.log(route);
            self.app.get(route.requestUrl, route.callbackFunction);}
        else if (route.requestType == 'post') {
            console.log(route);
            self.app.post(route.requestUrl, route.callbackFunction);}
        else if (route.requestType == 'delete') {
            console.log(route);
            self.app.delete(route.requestUrl, route.callbackFunction);}
    });
};



// 2- add routes below, 
productCategoryRouteConfig.prototype.addRoutes = function () {
    var self = this;
    
    //3 - createProductCategory, get req
    self.routeTable.push({
        requestType : 'get',     
        requestUrl : '/createProductCategory',
        callbackFunction : function (request, response) { 
            response.render('createProductCategory', { title : "Create Product Category" });
        }
    });

    //4 - createProductCategory, get req
    self.routeTable.push({ 
        requestType : 'post',
        //in vid he has no api here
        requestUrl : '/createProductCategory',
        callbackFunction : function (request, response) {
            var productCategoryDao = require('../server/Dao/productCategoryDao.js');
            console.log(request.body)
            productCategoryDao.productCategoryDao.createProductCategory(request.body, 
                function (status) { 
                response.json(status); 
                console.log(status);
            });
            
        }
    });


    // 5- add routes, /viewProductCategory, get req
    self.routeTable.push({
        requestType : 'get',     
        requestUrl : '/viewProductCategory',
        callbackFunction : function (request, response) { 
            response.render('viewProductCategory', { title : "View Product Category" });
        }
    });

   // 6
    self.routeTable.push({
        
        requestType : 'get',
        requestUrl : '/getAllProductCategory',
        callbackFunction : function (request, response) {
            
            var productCategoryDao = require('../Server/Dao/productCategoryDao.js');
            productCategoryDao.productCategoryDao.getAllProductCategory (
                function (productCategories) {
                    console.log(productCategories);
                    response.json({ productCategories : productCategories });
            });
            
        }
    });

};





module.exports = productCategoryRouteConfig;
```

**productCategoryController.js**

```js
//refer to the parent module
angular.module("productCategoryModule")
.controller("productCategoryController", productCategoryController);

//dependency injection, a timeout service,  inject the service we need productCategoryService
productCategoryController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout','productCategoryService'];

//constructor
function productCategoryController($scope, productCategoryService) {

  //define it as object, and it will have two properties
  $scope.productCategory = {

    categoryName: "",
    categoryDetails :""

  };

  $scope.createProductCategory = function(productCategory) {

   //the ervice has a metod called createProductCategory which we give the product category
   productCategoryService.createProductCategory(productCategory)
   .success(function(data){

        // $timeout(function() {}, 3000)
    
     

    });
   }

 }
```

**productCategoryService.js**

```js
//use same module, but make a factory, module hands data to the service
angular.module("productCategoryModule")
.factory("productCategoryService", productCategoryService);

//dependency injection, uses http, ajax service
productCategoryService.$inject = ['$http'];


function productCategoryService($http) {

return {

    //our services, first a method to take the categories from the controller
    //the services does things with the data from the controller
    createProductCategory: function(productCategory) {

        //post to this route /createProductCategory, here is the gate request
        return $http.post('/createProductCategory',
            //the data we are posting to the url
            {
                categoryName: productCategoryName,
                categoryDetails: productCategory.categoryDetails
            }


        );


    },

    //angular $http route endpoint

    getAllProductCategories: function() {

        return $http.get('/getAllProductCategory');
    }



};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have following code which contains invalid `HTML`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <style="padding-left:40%">
            <button type="button">  <class="btn btn-primary">
        <ng-click="createProductCategory(productCategory)">Create Product Category</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should be like this

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-left:40%">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createProductCategory(productCategory)">Create Product Category</button>
        </div>
 </div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nkTG4SMLEAtQRGEmtqBI?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Ravi! Now i get the console error :   angular.js:13920 TypeError: productCategoryService.createProductCategory is not a function
    at m.$scope.createProductCategory (productCategoryController.js:24)

Comment: Can you debug and see what's going wrong at that line 24

Comment: $scope.createProductCategory = function(productCategory) {

    
   productCategoryService.createProductCategory(productCategory)
   .success(function(data){

        // $timeout(function() {}, 3000)
    
     

    });
   }

Comment: I have told you to debug and see what's happening at line 24 not paste some code.

Comment: sorry do you mean use something to debug or just stare at it? lol have been looking at the for too many hours ;)

Comment: Put a debugger point at line 24 and see what data do you have when debugger hits that line..

Comment: $scope.createProductCategory = function(productCategory) {productCategory = Object {categoryName: "testname", categoryDetails: ""}  this comes up. i'm beginning to think the naming convention in the tutorial was really lazy and was maybe mixed up

Comment: Do you know how to debug JavaScript code? If you don't then search "how to debug JavaScript code chrome". You can change browser name based on the browser you use.

Comment: looked it up, put a breakpoint at line 24, and i see when I hit the button you helped me get working, the data i entered shows up in the scope line just above  $scope.createProductCategory = function(productCategory) { productCategory = Object {categoryName: "77777", categoryDetails: "g66666".   not sure where to go from here, thanks again

Comment: Put a debugger on the line where you call service function and when debugger hits that line press F11 key on keyboard then see whether debugger is going to the function you have in factory